# Magento 2 : How can i get My wishlist items by item id using javascript?

Tags: magento2

i tried following code. but its not worked

```
require([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function(customerData) {
    var wishlist = customerData.get('wishlist')();
    var itemId = 123; 
    var item = wishlist.items.find(function(item) {
        return item.id == itemId;
    });
    if (item) {
        console.log(item.name);
        console.log(item.price);
        console.log(item.sku);
        console.log(item.description);
    } else {
        console.log('Item not found in wishlist');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "item id" is the same as "product id" you need to obtain the `product_id` attribute.

So you need to change your `.find` method to check `item.product_id` instead of `item.id`.

By default you can get this information about items in wishlist:

```
add_to_cart_params
delete_item_params
image 
product_has_required_options
product_id
product_is_saleable_and_visible
product_name
product_price
product_sku
product_url
```